# REGEX: how to i get the name more the character " : "

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, nlp

Im using python to extract some info

i wanna get the words/names before the charcter `:`
but the problem is everythig is tied together

from here

```
Morgan Stanley.Erik Woodring:
```

i just wanna extract `"Erik Woodring:"`

or from here

```
market.Operator:
```

i just wanna extract `Operator:`

sometimes there are questiosn like this

```
to acquire?Tim Cook:
```

i just wanna extract `"Tim Cook:"`

this is what i tried

`\w*(?=.*:)`

this is not getting what i wanted, its returning a lot of words

Comment: `.*` matches as much as it can, which could include multiple `:`.  So `.*:` will match everything up to and including the last colon.  Instead, `.*?` matches as little as possible, so `.*?:` matches as little as possible up to the (next) colon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be the regex you're looking for:

```
\b[\w\s]+(?=:)
```

- **\b** world boundary;
- **[\w\s]+** matches any word or whitespace (at least one character);
- **(?=:)** positive lookahead that specifies the word must be followed by a punctation mark;

https://regex101.com/r/w86oWv/1

If you want to get the ":" too you can simply remove the lookahead:

```
\b[\w\s]+:
```